# Can't dismiss ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Please help, I can't dismiss ProgressDialog when the synchronization.The method sincronizaahora calls the method pre for show the progressdialog and The method 
actualizarDatosLocalesProductos calls the method pre for dismiss the progressdailog but it doesn't working.

```js
private void actualizarDatosLocalesProductos(JSONObject response, SyncResult syncResult)
    {
        JSONArray productos = null;
        int j=3;
        try
        {
            // Obtener array "productos"
            productos = response.getJSONArray(Constantes.PRODUCTOS);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Parsear con Gson
        Producto[] res = gson.fromJson(productos != null ? productos.toString() : null, Producto[].class);
        List<Producto> data = Arrays.asList(res);
        // Lista para recolección de operaciones pendientes
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        // Tabla hash para recibir las entradas entrantes
        HashMap<String, Producto> expenseMap = new HashMap<String, Producto>();
        for (Producto e : data) {
            expenseMap.put(e.idProducto, e);
        }

        // Consultar registros remotos actuales
        Uri uri = ContractParaDatos.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTO;
        String select = ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.ID_REMOTA + " IS NOT NULL";
        Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, PROJECTION_PRODUCTOS, select, null, null);
        assert c != null;
        Log.i(TAG, "Se encontraron " + c.getCount() + " registros locales.");
        // Encontrar datos obsoletos
        String id;
        String nombre;
        Double precio;
        Double iva;

        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            syncResult.stats.numEntries++;
            id = c.getString(COLUMNA_ID_REMOTA);
            nombre = c.getString(COLUMNA_PRODUCTO);
            precio = c.getDouble(COLUMNA_PRECIO);
            iva = c.getDouble(COLUMNA_IVA);
            Producto match = expenseMap.get(id);
            if (match != null) {
                // Esta entrada existe, por lo que se remueve del mapeado
                expenseMap.remove(id);
                Uri existingUri = ContractParaDatos.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTO.buildUpon().appendPath(id).build();
                // Comprobar si el producto necesita ser actualizado
                boolean b = match.nombrePrd != null && !match.nombrePrd.equals(nombre);
                boolean b1 = match.precioPrd != precio;
                boolean b2 = match.IVA != iva;

                if (b || b1 || b2)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Programando actualización de: " + existingUri);
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(existingUri)
                            .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.PRODUCTO, match.nombrePrd)
                            .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.PRECIO, match.precioPrd)
                            .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.IVA, match.IVA)
                            .build());
                    syncResult.stats.numUpdates++;
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No hay acciones para este registro: " + existingUri);
                }
            } else {
                // Debido a que la entrada no existe, es removida de la base de datos
                Uri deleteUri = ContractParaDatos.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTO.buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(id).build();
                Log.i(TAG, "Programando eliminación de: " + deleteUri);
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(deleteUri).build());
                syncResult.stats.numDeletes++;
            }
        }
        c.close();
        // Insertar items resultantes
        for (Producto e : expenseMap.values())
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Programando inserción de: " + e.idProducto);
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContractParaDatos.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTO)
                    .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.ID_REMOTA, e.idProducto)
                    .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.PRODUCTO, e.nombrePrd)
                    .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.PRECIO, e.precioPrd)
                    .withValue(ContractParaDatos.ColumnasProducto.IVA, e.IVA)
                    .build());
            syncResult.stats.numInserts++;
        }

        if (syncResult.stats.numInserts > 0 ||
                syncResult.stats.numUpdates > 0 ||
                syncResult.stats.numDeletes > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Aplicando operaciones...");

            try
            {
                resolver.applyBatch(ContractParaDatos.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            resolver.notifyChange(
                    ContractParaDatos.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTO,
                    null,
                    false);
            Log.i(TAG, "Sincronización finalizada.");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Termino", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//<-----------------------------------------------------


            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////77777
            try {
                pre(context, j);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No se requiere sincronización");
        }
    }
```

```js
public  static void sincronizarAhora(Context context, boolean onlyUpload, boolean rutas)
    {
        int j=2;
        Log.i(TAG, "Realizando petición de sincronización manual");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Cargando Datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//<-----------------------------------------------------
        try {
            pre(context, j);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContractParaDatos.NUMERO_RUTA, rutas);
        if (onlyUpload)
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_UPLOAD, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(obtenerCuentaASincronizar(context),
                context.getString(R.string.provider_authority), bundle);
    }
```

```js
public static void pre(Context context, int i) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException
    {
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        if (i==2)
        {
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Cargando Anuncios");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Espere un momento...");
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        else if (i==3 || mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a new progress dialog in `pre()` method? Shouldn't you be declaring it global and then use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare your progressDialog in class scope, and instantiate it just one time, the below code do all the work for you.
You can pass the context to your method or in class constructor if you are out of android component that has a context...

```
public void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.setMessage(message);
        } else {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage(message);
            try {
                progressDialog.show();
            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
                // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
                // has leaked window
            }
        }
    }

public void dismissProgressDialog(){
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            try {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
                // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
                // has leaked window
            }
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate ProgressDialog in your main thread/activity like @Yashasvi told

```
private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

// Main thread/activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Cargando Anuncios");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Espere un momento...");

}


public static void pre(Context context, int i) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    if (i==2)
    {
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    else if (i==3 || mProgressDialog.isShowing())
    {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Complete Solution

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Cargando Anuncios");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Espere un momento...");

        try {
            pre(this, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void pre(Context context, int i) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException
    {
        if (i==2)
        {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        else if (i==3 || mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I declare it global in the method pre() I have a error with the varible. The error is Non-static field "mProgressDialog" cannot be referenced from a static  context.